# How to return and display an error message from within a exception try catch

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have a Login/sign up page that is connected to firebase. When the user tries to log in with an incorrect account/password, there is a `switch case` nestled in the `catch` that catches and prints the appropriate error to the console.

```
on PlatformException catch (e) {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      switch (e.message) {
        case 'There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.':
          errorType = authProblems.UserNotFound;
          break;
}
print('The error is $errorType');
```

I would like to add a `return` statement with a `String` that can be used in a `Text`widget to display to the user an appropriate message.

The try catch is in a validate/submit class that is called when the user selects to Login/Sign up.

I could add more code if it would help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call "setState" inside the catch.

```
setState(() {
  /* update a variable to track the state of the error */
});
```